# Symfony Doctrine generate entities from multiple databases

Tags: symfony, doctrine, multiple-databases

With Doctrine in Symfony2 there is a simple way to start a project with reverse-engineered Entities created from existing database schema. It is quite well documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html). There is not mentioned how to reverse-engineer data from a non-default database when using multiple databases (which is documented [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)).

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473366/symfony-2-generate-entities-from-multiple-databases), it works like this:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert --em="troller" --from-database yml ./src/NAMESPACE/NAMEBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm
```

However, I'm just getting the exception as if the second entity manager didn't exist. Even though I have config.yml according to docs.

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                            
Doctrine ORM Manager named "troller" does not exist.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you specify an `entity manager` with "troller" name?

You can do this with a snippet of code like this (into `app/config/config.yml` file)

```
orm:
  default_entity_manager:   default
  entity_managers:
    default:
      connection:       default
      mappings:
        AcmeDemoBundle: ~
        AcmeStoreBundle: ~
    troller:
      connection:       troller
      mappings:
        YourTrollerBundle: ~
```

In this example, you've defined two entity managers called `default` and `troller`. The default entity manager manages entities in the `AcmeDemoBundle` and `AcmeStoreBundle`, while the `troller` entity manager manages entities in the `YourTrollerBundle`. *You've also defined two connections, one for each entity manager.*

Obiously define a new connection and entity manager, isn't enaugh: you have to specify "connection parameters" also (like db name, user, password, driver, and so on)

```
troller:
  driver:   "%database_driver2%"
  host:     "%database_host2%"
  port:     "%database_port2%"
  dbname:   "%database_name2%"
  user:     "%database_user2%"
  password: "%database_password2%"
  charset:  UTF8
```

Comment: It helps me too, btw if you may not set specific mapping option.